# any() no funciona correctamente

Tags: python

tengo un problema con la función "any()" ya que al querer utilizar un 1 o un 0 el programa se comporta tal como se espera, pero una vez utilizamos un numero mayor a 1 el programa deja de funcionar como se espera y no da el resultado esperado, ya que como podemos ver en la posición [0,0] de la matriz tenemos un 2, sin embargo el programa no es capaz de encontrar ese 2

```
import numpy as np

M5 = np.zeros([2, 10])
M5[0, 0] = 2
print(M5)

if M5.any() == 2:
    print('found')

else:
    print ('Nothing')
```

Comment: Según tu, que hace `any`?

Comment: Por si no sabías `any` comprueba si algún valor es `True`, es decir, `any` retorna `True` si algún elemento de una lista (o nparray en tu caso) es verdadero y `False` si no. Al compararlo con 2 tu `True` es evaluado como `1` (1 `True` y 0 `False`) por lo que la condición fallará .

Comment: Si tu quieres comprar si el nparray tiene en algún lugar el número (o elemento) que deseas buscar debes colocar el parámetro `where`. Tu condición quedaría así `if MS.any(where = [2]): print("found")`

Answer (score 0):

El método `any()` retorna `True` or `False`; no lo compares con 2, pues

```
True == 2 => False
```

La forma correcta es

```
import numpy as np

M5 = np.zeros([2, 10])
M5[0, 0] = 2
print(M5)

if M5.any():
    print('found')
else:
    print ('Nothing')
```